# SlideToggle multiple separate divs

Tags: jquery

```js
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
        jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
        jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
        jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
 

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

I got this code but it does not work how i want. When i click, for example, on div2 whereas div2 stills open, i need to close it, not open it once again.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `target` visibility before performing any action as follows:

```js
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              
              var targetElem = jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target'));
              if(targetElem.is(":visible"))
                  targetElem.hide();
              else
              {
                  jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
                  jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
                  targetElem.slideToggle();
              }
        });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
 

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chek for target element either exist or not first, then do hide and show :

```js
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
              //jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              if ( jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target') ).is(':visible') )
                 jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideUp();
              else
                 jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown();
        });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
 

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `siblings` to hide already showed divs and just `slideToggle()` the target

```js
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              var getTarget = $(this).attr('target');
              $('#div'+getTarget).siblings('.targetDiv').slideUp();
              $('#div'+getTarget).slideToggle();
        });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
 

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** function for excluding the div with ID in the `.targetDiv` selection or you can use :not() pseudo selector.

```js
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
        var targetId = $(this).attr('target');
        jQuery('.targetDiv').not( jQuery('#div' + targetId) ).slideUp();
        jQuery( '#div'+ targetId ).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
 

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```